# Solve sine and exponential nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Is it possible to solve this kind of differential equation with forward Euler?

$$\ddot y^2 + sin(\ddot y ) + \dot y + y = u$$

I haven't even write this ODE on the first order form. If I would do that, I would say $\dot y = x_2$ and $y = x_1$. Then the ODE would be:

$$x_2 = \dot x_1$$
$$\dot x_2^2 + sin(\dot x_2 ) + x_2 + x_1 = u$$

Then I move all the derivatives to the LHP and non-derivatives to RHP.

$$\dot x_1 = x_2 $$
$$\dot x_2^2 + sin(\dot x_2 )= u -  x_2 - x_1 $$

But how about these: $\dot x_2^2 + sin(\dot x_2 )$ ? My goal is to find $\dot x_2$.

Comment: You can't find $\dot{x}_2$ explicitly.

Comment: And in many cases also not uniquely, especially if $2\dot x_2+\cos(\dot x_2)=0$ or close to this point.

Comment: @xpaul So the highest order need to be alone?

Comment: $x^2 + \sin(x)$ is not a one-to-one function of $x$.

Comment: what is $u$ ? ...

Comment: @JJacquelin it's the input signal.

Comment: So $u$ is a function of $t$. The ODE cannot be analytically solved for a closed form of $y(t,u(t))$. Numerical method of solving is required.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thank you. You can write your answer here and I will accept it.